# How to run a cronjob 10 times in 30 minutes from one specific hour?

Tags: cron

I would like to know if it's possible to run a cronjob for 10 times within 30 minutes (run it every 3 minutes) starting at 8:00 and finishing at 8:30 every day.

The files I would like to run are PHP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to list out in your cron tab:

```
0,3,6,9,12,18,21,24,27,30 8 * * * php -f path/to/your/file.php
```

If you need to run multiple php scripts, I would collate them in a .sh file and execute them from there.

```
0,3,6,9,12,18,21,24,27,30 8 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

If you need to run a separate php script each time, you will have to create individual cron entries such as:

```
0 * * * php -f path/to/your/file1.php
3 * * * php -f path/to/your/file2.php
```

Comment: Awesome @NGRhodes - I didn't now you were able to concatenate minutes using the comma. That's everything I need as I am running the same script. And by the way, I am using `wget -q path/to/your/file.php` to run the command. Don't know if that's less correct than `php -f path/to/your/file.php`

Comment: I don't think there will be much difference for local files. Don't forget to mark the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works just fine, but can be simplified to:

```
0-30/3 8 * * *
```

Which sets the range with dash, and the steps with slash. See it in [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru/#0-30/3_8_*_*_*) for a more verbose explanation.